# GCD of a list in scheme

Tags: scheme

I wondering how I would write the  gcd functions over an entire list in scheme. I've been trying to learn the language and came across the question for one of the other languages and was curious.

So far, this is what I have. Running just gives me an error.

```
(define insert (x xs)
    (if (null? xs)
        (list1 x)
        (if (< x (car xs))
            (cons x xs)
            (cons (car xs) (insert x (cdr xs))))))

;; DEFINE insertion-sort HERE

(define insertion-sort(l)
    (if (null? cdr l)   
        l
        (cons (insert (car l) (cdr l)) (insertion-sort (cdr l) ) )
    )
)
```

Comment: Do it recursively. `(gcd x y z)` is the same as `(gcd x (gcd y z))`

Comment: `(define x (a ...) ...)` should be `(define (x a ...) ...)`.

Comment: You need to take more care with your parentheses. (It looks like you have been copying Common Lisp code instead of paying attention in class.)

Comment: What does calculating the GCD have to do with insertion sort?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the GCD is an operation which is both commutative and associative.  This means that (gcd a b c) = (gcd a (gcd b c)) = (gcd (gcd a b) c).

So all you need to do is make a procedure which finds the GCD for two numbers (say using Euclid's algorithm) and then fold/reduce over your list of numbers using that procedure.